If an answerer does not sufficiently clarify their answer, should I post a new question about that answer?
A recent question of mine has received an answer that I generally believe to be relevant due to the high expertise and reputation of the answer-giver.
Unfortunately, my requests for clarification of a decisive paragraph of the answer could not be satisfied, which leaves me in a situation where I can neither vote on said answer, nor accept it. And also I would like to understand the application that was alluded to.
I think further requests for clarification are pointless. Should I post a new question asking for clarification of an existing answer? I am afraid this could be received as a passively-offensive action.

I see no problem with posting a new question if (a) it is distinct from your original question and (b) the new question can be answered by anyone (i.e., it's not "what did you mean in this answer?"). I wouldn't worry about offending a user who refuses to clarify on the grounds that you didn't upvote an unclear answer -- it's his choice not to clarify, just as it's your choice not to upvote an unclear answer.

I gave you an application example of where adding external barrier capacitance would be decisively inappropriate. I gave you that example because it seemed it would help you. The fact that your knowledge didn't cover the example given doesn't mean you can expect a full tear-down of what that application is. In these circumstances it is appropriate to raise a new post about the example application if you are interested in it. It's not appropriate (IMHO) to keep badgering me about it when you have the easy option of raising a new post.

@Andyaka Fine it is resolved now

Out of interest, as someone with currently less than 10k rep, the answer in the question isn't visible. Was the answer deleted?

@ChesterGillon yes it was deleted after this meta question was posted. However the meta question is general and not limited to the particular question that I linked above.
